# PyroCMS error - Undefined Property

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have created a site with Pyro on my local server which is running fine.

I've put it onto a staging server and it's throwing an error in model.php in the Codeigniter system.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Pages::$session

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 50
```

At line 50 is

```
function __get($key)
{
    $CI =& get_instance(); //50
    return $CI->$key;
}
```

In the PHP error log though, it logs

```
Call to a member function set_flashdata() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/system/pyrocms/modules/modules/models/module_m.php
```

The full output of the debug is below

```
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/pages/config/routes.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config for dev environment is not found. Trying global config.
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config file loaded: system/pyrocms/config/asset.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config for dev environment is not found. Trying global config.
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config file loaded: system/pyrocms/config/language.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config for dev environment is not found. Trying global config.
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Config file loaded: system/pyrocms/config/tags.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Helper loaded: debug_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:00 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: text_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: asset_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: pagination_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: array_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: gravatar_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/comments/helpers/comments_helper.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/modules/helpers/module_helper.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/users/helpers/user_helper.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Language file loaded: language/english/main_lang.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Language file loaded: language/english/errors_lang.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/users/language/english/user_lang.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Database config for dev environment is not found. Trying global config.
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Helper loaded: inflector_helper
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/modules/models/module_m.php
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> File loaded: system/pyrocms/modules/modules/helpers/module_helper.php
ERROR - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 167 of 1315 bytes /var/www/vhosts/site_here/httpdocs/system/pyrocms/modules/modules/models/module_m.php 191
ERROR - 2011-07-01 11:19:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined property: Pages::$session /var/www/vhosts/site_here/httpdocs/system/codeigniter/core/Model.php 50
```

I don't know if this is a config issue on the server but these are core files which I've not changed.

Any ideas?

Ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a [PyroCMS bug](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/issues/438) in some early versions that should have since been fixed. Upgrade perhaps?

EDIT: the bug is occuring because the session variable is somehow not being set. I'd look for differences between the `application/config/config.php` and `application/config/autoload.php` files on the local server and the staging server: they must somehow handle the session setup differently.

Comment: I'm on 1.2 (not beta) :( Thank you.

Comment: Ah: the bug was marked as of 1.2.0, and there's a comment in there that certain folks are still seeing it? There is a 1.2.1 release at https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/tree/release%2Fv1.2.1: try that, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried upgrading to that and it isn't working sadly.

Comment: This is just a guess, but your server is running PHP 5 right?

Comment: Femi - The only thing I have changed is to remove index.php from $config['index_page'] and that is the same on both of them.

Jack - Yes - Running on 5.2.17

Comment: I installed the latest version and added my theme to it and then did imported each table for the database and it worked fine. Thanks.